# Does “lɪən” really sound like “lyən”?

Tags: pronunciation

The **lyən** is in phonetics of words like **million** and **billion**. And both **lɪən** and **lyən** are in the BRE and AME phonetics of *Brazilian* respectively.

I have been using **lɪən** sound. And I think they are different when pronounced slowly but are same in speech. Please help on these sound.

Clarification: I hear the word like mil**lion** sound like a**lien**. I mean the vowel sound is like **Ian** Fleming name. Is it true?

Comment: I think the main difference between the (standard) BrE and AmE pronunciations of the second syllable of "million" is in the "o" sound not the "i" sound.  The British pronounce it more like a long "o" and we Americans more like a short "u", *"mill-ee-ohn"* vs. *"mill-ee-un"*.   But why ask here?  Why not just listen to the samples:  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/million

Comment: Over the past decade or so, in line with the increasing "internationalisation" of science and technology, I've noticed that an increasing number of *British* native speaker scientists now vocalise the /r/ in ***iron*** so as to distinguish it from ***ion***. I guess they just gave up the unequal struggle when faced with blank looks from their international colleagues whenever they mention something like ***iron ions*** in discussions and lectures. But that's one context where BrE *scientists* aren't *mainstream* native speakers.

Comment: (Popular facetious definition: ***irony = ferrous*** :)

Comment: Are you using IPA for both of your examples?

Comment: I dunno, Andrew. Seems like a stretch to me.

Comment: Apparently not @maciej. In IPA we use /j/ not /y/ for the <y> sound in **y**es.

Comment: @Andrew, I don't know of _any_ phonetical alphabet that would allege that "o" in "million" would actually be pronounced as "o". It is a shwa (ə) all the way.

Comment: @tenebris2020  Now that I'm more awake, I agree both  recordings on the Cambridge site sound the same.  I guess I'm thinking of a  different accent.

Comment: @Andrew, that's the nature of [schwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa). It can lean a bit to various sounds. It's kind of in the middle of everything.

Answer (score 2):

There is no actual difference in pronunciation. You might have been confused by the different ways that you saw it written (different transcriptions) in a British dictionary and in an American dictionary. However, it's not because of any difference in pronunciation. It's just because there are different phonetic alphabets, so different signs might be used in them to represent things that are the same.

As the [Wikipedia article on the International Phonetic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) states,

> Many British dictionaries, including the Oxford English Dictionary and some learner's dictionaries such as the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary and the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary, now use the International Phonetic Alphabet to represent the pronunciation of words.[34] However, most American (and some British) volumes use one of a variety of pronunciation respelling systems, intended to be more comfortable for readers of English. For example, the respelling systems in many American dictionaries (such as Merriam-Webster) **use ⟨y⟩ for IPA [j]** and ⟨sh⟩ for IPA [ʃ], reflecting common representations of those sounds in written English,[35] using only letters of the English Roman alphabet and variations of them. (In IPA, [y] represents the sound of the French ⟨u⟩ (as in tu), and [sh] represents the pair of sounds in grasshopper.)
>   You might have just seen different ways of representing the same sound.

Please pay attention to what I've marked in bold font in the above paragraph:

> **use ⟨y⟩ for IPA [j]**

You might just be dealing with different phonetic alphabets in your example.

The specific way phonemes are pronounced can be wildly different not only in different dialects, but simply from one person to another. In fact, there is a linguistical term for a bulk of specific sounds that are **different** from one another if they were to be analyzed on a spectrograph, but they represent **the same** phoneme. These are called *[allophones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allophone)*. In fact, a phoneme is largely an abstraction. That is why, as was noted in comments to your question, it is just best to listen to how native speakers pronounce words and to try to imitate that. (Keeping in mind that native speakers will still pronounce things slightly different, irrespective of whether they are, say, British rather than American, or vice versa.)

Bottom line is, different ways of "writing phonetics" don't necessarily mean that there is an actual difference in *ideal* pronunciation. There are differences in *real* pronunciations, because phonemes are continuums of different sounds (allophones). But you should not build a theory out of it.

Comment: Despite all technical phonological/phonetic transcription explanations, I do not hear any BrE/AmE difference in billion or million. And I listen to CNN and the BBC all the time. I don't hear the BBC presenters say it any differently than the CNN presenters, for example.

Comment: @Lambie I do not see and hear any differences either. My understanding is that the OP was confused by the different ways that he saw it _written_ (different transcriptions). And he then started hearing this into what he was listening to. This is what I tried to explain to him—that the different ways of "writing phonetics" don't necessarily mean that there is an actual difference in _ideal_ pronunciation. However, since phonemes are continuums of different sounds (allophones), he might certainly have come across _slightly_ different ways of pronouncing stuff.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your general idea but you didn't address the actual question i.e. that there is not difference in pronunciation here.

Comment: @Lambie, I'll edit my post accordingly.

Comment: @Lambie, done. Put the gist in the very first paragraph.

Comment: It seems like you have misunderstood my question. So I’ll clarify my question.

Comment: @user67265 Your clarification hasn't clarified anything. You seem to have misunderstood my answer. You are basing yourself on a mistaken premise that since you saw "million" transcribed with [lɪən] in a British dictionary and with [lyən] in an American dictionary, then this is somehow different pronunciations. No, they are not different—just the way of writing them down is different. "Ian" in "Ian Fleming" is most certainly pronounced VERY different from "-ion" in "million", because "I" in "Ian" is stressed, and "i" in "-ion" is unstressed and is shortened, it's [ˈmɪljən] in IPA.

Comment: @tenebris2020 Great. I’m confused because I’ve watched videos about this sound, such as [this one](https://youtu.be/CxaNnsbCRk4). The speaker said mil-yn, but when she spoke the word fast I heard no Y. So is it ok to remove the y?

Comment: @user67265 The way the girl in the video transcribes it – [mil-y'n] – is absolutely wrong (maybe her font lacked a sign for ə). So let's break it down: after mil-, what you hear next is what is transcribed [j] in IPA. It is a _shortened_ "i" sound identical to the one which you hear at the beginning of "York" (as in "New York"). After that, there is an unstressed [ə], which is a "reduced", "in-between" sound, a sound which can be an "uncareful" version of "a", or "e", or "u". **And "j" doesn't disappear when you say it quickly.** It's just less noticeable. But it's still there.